# SAS Macro Code in loop using array

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I wrote SAS code and I need to pass value depending upon  the parameter value .. SAS Code run and get the required output

```
%MACRO FTIC(Student_Entry=, Admission_Year=,YEAR_TRACK=, TERM=, College );
...
...
...
%MEND FTIC;

%FTIC(Student_Entry= A, Admission_Year=2012 ,YEAR_TRACK=1, TERM=Summer/FALL )
```

Here are the values for each parameter:
    Student_Entry= A, B,C, D

```
Admission_year = 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016

Year_Track = 1, 2,3,4,5

Term= Summer/Fall, Spring
```

I am writing below lines more than 4*4*5*2 times lines. to achieve my result.

```
%FTIC(Student_Entry= A, Admission_Year=2012 ,YEAR_TRACK=1, TERM=Summer/FALL )
```

Can you please tell me how-how to write this more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It looks like you want some way to automatically loop through these parameters and call the %FTIC macro for each combination of parameters.

1. Create lists for the possible values of each parameter.

   `%let stud_list = A B C D;

   %let Ad_list = 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016;

   %let YrT_list = 1 2 3 4 5;

   %let term_list = Summer/Fall Spring;`
2. Count the items in each list.

   `%let stud_cnt = %sysfunc(countw(&stud_list),%str( ));

   %let Ad_cnt = %sysfunc(countw(&Ad_list),%str( ));

   %let YrT_cnt = %sysfunc(countw(&YrT_list),%str( ));

   %let term_cnt = %sysfunc(countw(&term_list),%str( ));`
3. Use a %do loop in a dummy macro to repeatedly call the %FTIC Macro.

   `%macro dummy;

     %do i = 1 %to &stud_cnt;
       %do ii = 1 %to &ad_cnt;
         %do iii = 1 %to &yrt_cnt;
           %do iiii = 1 %to &term_cnt;
             %FTIC(student_entry = %scan(&stud_list,&i,%str( )),
             Admission_year = %scan(&Ad_list,&ii,%str( )),
             Year_track = %scan(&YrT_list,&iii,%str( )),
             Term = %scan(&term_list,&iiii,%str( ))
             );
             %end;
           %end;
         %end;
      %end;
   %mend dummy;
   %dummy;`